# Python for loop - Can i skip an a number of iterations from condition set inside the loop?

Tags: python, loops

I have a for loop that iterates through a range, but I would like it to skip a number of iterations based on a condition. This is the code:

```
for i in range(1,100):

    if some_condition:
        i += some_number
```

What I am trying to accomplish: So let's say i=5 the some_condition is triggered and some_number=2, this would set i= 7, and then the next i that we iterate to will be 8, so we never iterate through 6 and 7. How can I do this?

Comment: Use a `while` loop instead. `i = 1   while i < 100: ... i += 1` then you can adjust the value of `i` inside the loop

Comment: @Nick Thank you! I should have thought of that!

Answer (score 5):

It might be easier to use a `while` loop:

```py
increment = 2

i = 1
while i < 100:
    if some_condition:
        i += increment
    i += 1
```

Since a `for` loop reassigns the iterator to the next item in the iterable, whatever you do in the `for` clause has no effect on the iterator the next time the loop iterates.

Comment: @Nick Good point. Actually, I think OP wanted `i` to increment by 1 even if the condition is `True`.

Comment: duh! a while loop! (after 14 hours of working on this program I am clearly losing my mind lol) thank you!

Comment: @Kat No problem! Happens to the best of us :)